# Showing that a certain signal to noise ratio is bounded by one (matrix inequality)

Tags: symmetric-matrices, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, positive-matrices

Let $A, \, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be $n \times n$, symmetric, positive definite matrices.

> I would like to show that for any column vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, it holds that
> $$ 0 \le \frac{(x^TA^{-1}x)^2}{(x^TB^{-1}x)(x^TA^{-1} B A^{-1}x) }\le 1.$$

In signal processing literature, if $A$ and $B$ are certain covariance matrices, then the fractional quantity I write above is sometimes referred to as the *normalized signal to interference plus noise ratio*. Showing this quantity is bounded below by zero is trivial, because of the positive definiteness of all the matrices involved. On the other hand, I probably need to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in a clever way to show it bounded from above by one. This is where I am stuck. Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, noticing that

$$x^T A^{-1} x = x^T B^{-1/2} B^{1/2} A^{-1}x = (B^{-1/2}x)^T B^{1/2} A^{-1}x.$$